# Webpack : Configure css file paths

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, path

In Webpack, how to configure css loaders to use css files from specific path? I tried below code to fetch files from path 'src/styles', but did not work.

```
rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        'css-loader'
                    ],
                    include: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, "src/styles/" ),
                    ]

                }
      ]
```

I have 'style.css' under 'src/styles' folder. In 'index.js' I just did

import 'style.css'

because I want path to be resolved from loader.
When I build, getting below error:

```
**ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style.css' in 'D:\webpack-demo\src'
 @ ./src/index.js 2:0-19**
```

Please help.

Comment: How exactly it "did not work"?

Comment: Try removing the trailing `/`: `path.resolve(__dirname, "src/styles" ),`

Comment: Added more details on error, in the question above.